# Force sap.m.List to load item

Tags: sapui5

I have a list with `growingThreshold` set to 50 . I have 100 records. The function `list.getItems()` returns only the first 50 due to the threshold.

My question is:  Is there a way to force the list to load a specific item? For example, I know that there are 100 records and I want to select the 61st record.

Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Would it not make sense to set the growingTreshold to 100 or even remove the growing feature? What kind of data model (JSON/OData) are you using?

Comment: It is possible with a `filter`. You just have to know the unique key of the 61st record (an ID or something).